# Twitter bootstrap or JQuery Mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

We are about to start the development of a new website, which we want to render correctly on Desktop computers and also on the mobile devices(tablets & phones).

Should we be using the Responsive Web Design approach for this requirement?

How is Jquery Mobile framework different from the Twitter Bootstrap tool? And which is would be better option for the above requirement?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Responsive web design approach would render your site correctly on desktop, tablets, phone.
There are many links comparing Jquery Mobile and Bootstrap. Below is one of them. A lot depends on what else you need your site to do.

[twitter-bootstrap vs jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242012/twitter-bootstrap-vs-jquery-mobile?rq=1)