# Jquery mobile VS JQuery and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have stuck a bit with what to choose .So i have a few questions .

1) If i want to create website which will work well on mobile and desktop without loosing any performance on mobile (like do not work buttons or effects) so what should i use Jquery mobile or Bootstrap and Jquery?

2) Why when we include Jquery mobile  we also  have to  import just Jquery ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

3) Is Jquery(not mobile) stucking on mobiles ?

Thank you every one for your time )).

Comment: what do you mean by stucking?

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9242012/5934435